# How to import an environment?

Tags: r

Suppose that `e` is an environment object.

Is there a simple way to import `e`'s contents into the current environment (creating or overwriting symbols as the case may be)?

Comment: Probably `attach()`, though I've never used it for that.

Comment: `list2env(as.list(e), .GlobalEnv)` should also work.

Comment: Why do you believe you'd need this?

Comment: @nrussell:  Thanks.  That's actually very close to what I'm looking for.  Based on your comment, I figured that what I'm looking for is `list2env(as.list(e), envir = environment())`.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the names of things in your environment, create things with the same names and values in the Global Environment:

```
lapply(names(e),function(n){assign(n,get(n,env=e),env=.GlobalEnv)})
```

In action:

```
> foo = "global foo"
> e = new.env()
> e$foo="from env"
> e$bar = 1234
> foo
[1] "global foo"
> lapply(names(e),function(n){assign(n,get(n,env=e),env=.GlobalEnv)})
[[1]]
[1] "from env"

[[2]]
[1] 1234

> foo
[1] "from env"
```

This might break if the things in the environment are environments... I've not really thought it through....

Note this would appear to be the hard way, and `list2env(as.list(e), .GlobalEnv)` looks like it does it in one.

Answer (score 2):

Based on nrussel's comment, I figured that what I'm looking for is

```
list2env(as.list(e), envir = environment())
```